# Git updates automatic notification

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I'm trying to create a script that will email me if we have any updates for Git. I assume there are several easier/harder ways of doing this. Also, I have noticed that there are no highlighting colours for the text, all the text is the default colour. I thought the text, depending if it's a variable or in a function would be a different colour text.

```
#!/bin/bash
email="my_email@my_domain"
var="yum list available git"

if ["$var"]
then
echo $var | mail -s "Gitlab Updates" $email
fi
```

When I run the command for a test, I get the following:

```
./testEmail.sh: line 6: [yum list available git]: command not found
```

I assume I'm doing multiple things wrong here, I would just like a clean and simple script to email me when we have Git updates.

Distro - Fedora 20

Comment: what is the normal output of `yum list available git`  ? does she provide an empty output if there is no updates?

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the output of $var is just that (yum list available git), it's not the result of the command. To be able to have $var contain a command you have to define it like so:

```
var=$(yum list available git)
```

the condition if [[ $var ]] doesn't say more than if $var exists. So it does not compare the output of $var to anything. Thus your script should look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
email="my_email@my_domain"
var="yum list available git | grep git | wc -l"

if [ $var -ge 1 ]; then
    echo "Git updates available" | mail -s "Gitlab Updates" $email
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH

email="my_email@my_domain"
var=$(yum list available git)

if [ "$var" ] 
then
echo $var | mail -s "Gitlab Updates" $email
fi
```

This script worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You have to export your $PATH within the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH

email="my_email@my_domain"
var="yum list available git"

if [ "$var" ] ##I added spaces before the first and after the last quotes. 
then
echo $var | mail -s "Gitlab Updates" $email
fi
```

After doing that, I was able to get the script to work on a Fedora 20 VM.

Comment: Might point out the required spaces around the square test brackets.

Comment: exporting the path has nothing to do with the fact that the script is not running the command attributed to the $var variable. In this case $var is nothing but a string of characters, not being interpreted as a command.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, Luke, Alex and Jeff, I've got my script working now.

Answer (score -1):

`#!/bin/bash
email="my_email@my_domain"
var="yum list available git"
[[ $($var) ]] && echo $var|mailx -s "Gitlab Updates" $email`